# redirect to /dev/null: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I would like to know if somebody could help me with this error:

> wc: Files/Unused-CMA_host.txt: No such file or directory

The file doesn't exist, then I want to redirect the output to /dev/null

I try with this sentence `> /dev/null 2>&1` which is working in other case, but not here:

`wc -l Files/Unused-CMA_host.txt | awk '{print $1}' > /dev/null 2>&1`

somebody know why?

thanks.

Comment: Explain what you're doing. If the txt file doesn't exist, what lines are you trying to count? Do you expect a count of 0, or an error, or what?

Comment: `wc -l Files/Unused-CMA_host.txt  2> /dev/null | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 5):

Redirections apply to individual components of a pipeline, not a pipeline as a whole. In your example, you only redirect `awk`'s standard output. To redirect the standard error and stardard output of the entire pipeline would require a command group such as

```
{ wc -l Files/Unused-CMA_host.txt | awk '{print $1}' ; } > /dev/null 2>&1
```

However, if the file doesn't exist, there won't be any standard output. Perhaps you want to redirect standard error to suppress the error message? Then you can simply use

```
wc -l Files/Unused-CMA_host.txt 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
```

In the case of a non-existent file, `awk` will simply read from an empty stream and do nothing.